# Types in storage containing (nested) mappings cannot be assigned to in constructing struct

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping, solidity-0.8.x

when i want construct struct it says:

```
TypeError: Types in storage containing (nested) mappings cannot be assigned to.
```

compiler version: `0.8.15`

sol src:

```
contract repo{

    struct Board{
        bool isActive;
        mapping(string => string) content;
        uint count;
        string[] checkSums;
        mapping(string => uint) indexController;
    }

    mapping(address => Board) _clips;
    address[] _allAddress;


    function register(address addr) public returns(bool){
        if(!isUserExist(addr)){
            _clips[addr] = Board({
                isActive: true,
                count: 0
            });
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the full contract? Cause in the _clips mapping it the adress map to Board(may be) but it says Clipboard and you haven't declared isUserExist outside the function to verify the condition. Please share the complete code.

Comment: @Ad-h0c no its not the full source but other parts do not effect on the problem, it points to that board struct

Answer (score 1):

This is because of, like the error says, the fact that there are mappings in your struct. Mappings can't be wholly "assigned" to another, so the compiler doesn't want you wholly assigning the struct that contains a mapping. The way around this is by assigning individual values, not the whole struct:

```
contract repo{

    struct Board{
        bool isActive;
        mapping(string => string) content;
        uint count;
        string[] checkSums;
        mapping(string => uint) indexController;
    }

    mapping(address => ClipBoard) _clips;
    address[] _allAddress;


    function register(address addr) public returns(bool){
        if(!isUserExist(addr)){
            _clips[addr].isActive = true;
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i know its insider mappings (the err clearly said that) , i can fix that simply by using contracts instead of struct but its kinda chaotic move about memory and gas fee , i looking for err reason or lighter solution (about gas fee)

Comment: @oyopui5-906iu95-06 I'm not sure what you mean by "using contracts instead of struct" or "chaotic move about memory and gas fee". Doing it the way my answer shows doesn't increase gas usage, has the same effect, and doesn't error. Also not sure what you mean by "looking for err reason", my answer explained the reason for the error

Comment: This answer is valid only if we initialize a single value - `isActive`. But if we try to do something like:   

`mapping(string => string) myContent;  
myContent["abc"] = "xyz";  
_clips[addr].content = myContect;  `

We still will get the error.

Comment: @CREESTL Yes, that's my point, that you can't assign a mapping to a mapping. You can only assign individual values to a mapping. You could copy one mapping to another entry by entry, but you can't just assign one mapping to another mapping